# why Crystal Report is not working in visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have 2 visual studios in my computer VS 2012, vs 2008 which both has .rpt i.e. crystal reports.

I installed **CRforVS_13_0_5** and it's working in VS 2012 ultimate but doesn't work in vs 2008 i.e. it throws error.

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'CrystalDecisions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

References show these files missing in yellow

```
Warning 1   The referenced component 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine' could not be found.   
Warning 2   The referenced component 'CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework' could not be found.    
Warning 3   The referenced component 'CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore' could not be found.    
Warning 4   The referenced component 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource' could not be found.    
Warning 5   The referenced component 'CrystalDecisions.Shared' could not be found.  
Warning 6   The referenced component 'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms' could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the version of Crystal Reports that supports Visual Studio 2008 (and runs on .Net Framework 3.5).  This should with most reports but it is older so there maybe issues if you're expecting fixes from newer versions that are working in 2012.  Check these links out to CR downloads for 2008:

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27917
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27942